# Is it possible to perform calculations on the data before returning the response?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to create an API, so that when an user requests certain type of data, I want to query database, and create an HTML based on that data and return it in side JSON.

I'm pretty new to the django and the rest framework, but I already learned how to create basic API that serializes the model and returns it. Now I want to do something before returning the data.

result will possibly look like this:

```
{
  "html_response": "<table> (table based on the data) </table>"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given you want to return a fairly customized response, it may be best to extend `APIView` directly, override `get()` and create the JSON that way. That would give you some flexibility, as opposed to trying to do the same thing with `ModelViewSet`s and `Serializer`s which are better suited to serializing out specific fields on the model.

For example, if your model was called `MyModel` and had an attribute called `value`, the following would create a table with a single column with each row holding `value`:

```
from rest_framework import views
from rest_framework.response import Response

class MyEndPoint(views.APIView):

    def get(self, request):
        table = ['<table>']
        for rec in MyModel.objects.all():
            table.append('<tr><td>{}</td></tr>'.format(rec.value))
        table.append('</table>')
        return Response({'html_response': ''.join(table)})
```

You'd need to then wire that up in your `urls.py`:

```
path('^html_table', myapp.views.MyEndPoint.as_view())
```

More information on creating views with `APIView` can be found [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/)

Comment: Excatly what I was looking for. Where can I find out more about this topic? I've been searching everywhere. Also is this a standard practice or just a hack? I appreciate it!

Comment: Should have put a link to the docs in the answer originally - but I've added it now. Extending `APIView` is perfectly ok, particularly if you need to do something specific which you can't easily do with the slightly more abstract components of Django Rest Framework. You can also use a [function based view](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/#function-based-views) to achieve the same thing.